# Play 2 Non Action methods in Controller

Tags: playframework-2.0

How could I create non-action function at a Play 2 controller? Is any way to create utilities functions for controller?

```
public class Register extends Controller {
  @BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.FormUrlEncoded.class)
  public static Result registerByForm() {
      .......

  }

  // this is utility function
  private static User getFacebookIdByToken(String fbToken) {
     FacebookClient facebookClient = new DefaultFacebookClient(fbToken);
     User user = facebookClient.fetchObject("me", User.class);
     return user;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Play 1.0 there was no way to distinguish a `static void foo()` non-action and an action, hence the `@Util` annotation. My guess would be that Play 2.0 can distinguish, based on the return type, if a method is an action or not, which should only get you into trouble if you, for whatever reason, want to create a `Result` returning method in a `Controller` that is not an Action.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can put it the way as you showed. Anyway I think that better place for the method is the `User` class.

Answer (score -1):

In Play 1.2 you can change the access modifier from **public** to **private**. [This post](http://redino.net/blog/2014/03/make-controller-method-non-action-play-framework-1-2/) explains more details